# RedirectToAction is swapping day and month on date

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller POST action that redirects to a GET method using RedirectToAction.

```
return RedirectToAction(SomeActionName, new {  date = someModel.someUTCDate });
```

I have implemented a custom model binder which parses dates using the assumed culture and timezone information, so I am intercepting this correctly. The basic steps in my problem:

1. POST action is called with a date/time string, which is GMT Standard Time if not specified otherwise
2. The custom model binder parses this date to a DateTime with a Kind of Utc, and this is bound correctly in the correct format to the model
3. The POST action redirects to GET using RedirectToAction with the date that was bound as UTC time on the model
4. MVC3 is now trying to bind a DateTime string value with the month and day swapped around

Somewhere between calling RedirectToAction and rebinding the DateTime value for the GET action, a string conversion is taking place, which appears to be swapping the month and the day around.

Is there a simple way of ensuring that the correct string conversion takes place without the overhead of having to manually convert it for each RedirectToAction call? I would really like to know where this route value to string conversion takes place and whether or not I could influence it to do the correct string conversion.

To illustrate what I have a bit better, I have a custom DateTime model binder

```
public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    ValueProviderResult value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

    if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.AttemptedValue) || value.AttemptedValue == "null")
    {
        return null;
    }

    return FormatHelper.ConvertStringFromGMT(value.AttemptedValue);
}
```

On redirect I am finding that the model binder's value.AttemptedValue is an incorrectly formatted string.

Comment: Do you mean that SomeActionName has a date as parameter and that date is not bound correctly ?

Comment: I mean that SomeActionName has a date as a parameter and that my custom model binder is receiving an incorrectly formatted string to bind for this value. I specify a DateTime value for the date parameter, and this gets converted to a string value somewhere in MVC which is incorrectly formatted.

Comment: I think the conversion is done in ModelBinder before binding to your action parameter. The DefaultModelBinder class uses different culture settings to perform type conversions from different
areas of the request data. The values obtained from URLs (the routing and query string data) are converted
using culture-insensitive parsing, but values obtained from form data are converted taking culture into
account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the issue is now resolved. As far as I can tell, when MVC gets the route values for your redirect, the route values are converted to query string parameters using the invariant culture. This is just some magic that happens behind the scenes. My solution to this problem was to override the controller methods RedirectToAction and RedirectToActionPermanent (the overloads that take a RouteValueDictionary). I iterate over the RouteValueDictionary and convert any date types here using the defined culture and timezone information. Fortunately all of my controllers were already inheriting from a custom base controller so the fix was simple to implement.

Comment: Can you show how to override RedirectToAction to convert the date types? I am having the same issue but I can't find how to convert the date types while leaving the default logic for the other types untouched.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I implemented it here and it worked.